# Where do the negative examples come from in relation extraction via distant supervision?

Tags: nlp

In the [coursera nlp](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wA-Wvclz8LQ#t=363) videos Dan Jurafsky shows how you can start with seeds, search for them in a corpus, and extract the features for instances of those seeds (although he does not say how nlp practitioners extract the features: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401313/in-semi-supervised-relation-extraction-how-do-you-create-features-from-seed-exa)

He then says that the instances of the seeds in the corpus count as positive examples for a supervised classifier. But a supervised classifier will need positive and negative examples. When NLP practitioners do this sort of relation extraction via distant supervision, where do the negative examples come from?

Comment: maybe from freebase?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, in distant supervision, the negative example generation is a heuristic approach, and is often corpus-dependent. For relation extraction, it is often assumed that the corpus is complete. Therefore, for a given pair of entities `(a,b)`, the absence of a relation between `a` and `b` in the corpus is taken as evidence of the fact that `a` and `b` are, in fact, unrelated. This provides the pair `(a,b)` as a negative example.

In Jurafsky's paper [Distant supervision for relation extraction without labeled data](http://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/mintz.pdf), for example, the authors buld an explicit relation called **`unrelated`** by randomly selecting entity pairs that do not appear in any Freebase relation. Note that just like the positive examples, the negative examples, too, can be noisy in distant supervision. I quote from sec. 6.3 of the same paper:

> *While it is possible that some of these entity pairs are in fact related but are wrongly omitted from the Freebase data, we expect that on average these
>   false negatives will have a small effect on the performance of the classifier.*

Note that this paper is from 2009. Researchers were quick to identify the phrase "we expect ... have a small effect ... ". More recent work on relation extraction using distant supervision tries to overcome the adverse effect of false negatives generated by simple heuristics like the one I just described. This happens because in reality, knowledge bases (e.g. Freebase) are often incomplete. A few examples:

1. A multi-instance learner used together with a passage retrieval model. The passage retrieval model ranks the negative examples to reflect the likelihood of them being *actually* negative. (ref. [Filling Knowledge Base Gaps for Distant Supervision of Relation Extraction](https://aclweb.org/anthology/P/P13/P13-2117.pdf))
2. Learn relations from *positive* and *unlabeled* examples instead of explicitly negative examples. (ref. [Distant Supervision for Relation Extraction with an Incomplete Knowledge Base](https://www.cs.nyu.edu/~min/index_files/BonanMin_NAACL2013.pdf))

Both papers are from 2013. A more detailed explanation or analysis of these approaches is, unfortunately, beyond the scope of SO.